# Convert dp values to px values usable inside WebView (dp to CSS px)

Tags: android

I'm creating an HTML page from scratch and placing values dynamically in it and then displaying it inside a `WebView`.

I'm trying to replicate the `ActionBar` (which appears in the app in other activities) inside the `WebView` (as HTML).

I know the height of the `Actionbar` and also the text size of the title inside it.

I'm retrieving the values from the `dimens` folder like so ...

`mTitleSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.actionbar_title_text); // 50dp
mActionbarH = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.actionbar_height); // 25sp`

... and placing them in the CSS of the html file.

My problem is that the values above are waaaay too large. The height of the action bar and the text size are way too large. The same `dimens` values are used to display the actionbar in the rest of the app (not webview, but native android `View` inside a `RelativeLayout`) and they look great.

So ... i'm guessing the converted `50dp` and `25sp` values in pixels don't mean the same inside a native `View` and inside a `WebView` ? Is the webpage rendered in another manner than a native app is ?

If so, how should one convert the `dp` to be able to used the `px` value in the `Webview` and still keep it looking as the rest of the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I only needed to divide the value by the density of the device

i.e.

`res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.actionbar_height) / res.getDisplayMetrics().density`

... and set that value in the `CSS` as `px`

That was it.

Answer (score 2):

To convert dip into px try this code:

```
   public static float dipToPixels(Context context, float dipValue) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, metrics);
}
```

The formula is: px = dp * (dpi / 160), for having on a 160 dpi screen. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more information.

You could try:

```
public static int convertDipToPixels(float dips)
{
    return (int) (dips * appContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: hei. thanks, but getDimensionPixelSize already does this. It's a good method to convert the values, but it's not exactly related to my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If the dp value is used in a context that implies size, like the android:layout_width attribute, the logic described for [Resources.getDimensionPixelSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize%28int%29)() will be used. That is, the px value will be rounded to the nearest integer value, with the special case that if px > 0, then the actual value will be at least 1.

If the dp value is used in a context that implies offset, like the android:insetLeft attribute of the Inset Drawable, the logic described for [Resources.getDimensionPixelOffset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelOffset%28int%29) will be used. That is, the px value will simply be truncated to an integer value.

Sometimes the unmodified floating point value is used, such as for the android:dashWidth attribute of the  tag in a Shape Drawable, but this is pretty rare. Usually either the size or the offset logic is used, even if the floating point value could be used.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Webview` interprets pixels as dp, so

```
body {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

Would actually have the same effect as a padding of 16dp set on an Android native view.